# Validation not automatically called except when using KVC key-value-coding access

Tags: objective-c, validation, key-value-coding

I implemented a KVC validation method that is called by coredata, but is not being called when I call 
person.name = @"alice";

is there a reason why KVC validation methods, in this case,

```
- (BOOL)validateName:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
    NSLog(@"validateName is validating...");    
    // ...    
}
```

is not being called when setting a value via property expression?

Another problem is that I can't get this to work either:

```
[person setValue:@"ok" forKey:@"name"];
```

My NSLog line NEVER gets called.

Anything I'm missing?

This class is a subclass of NSManagedObject.

Does that matter?

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Managed Object Validation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004807-SW1) documentation, validation methods are not run until the context is saved, or until you manually validate (with `-validateForUpdate:`, `-validateForInsert:`, or `-validateForDelete:`).

Comment: Yeah you are right... I should have read the docs more closely.  This does get called by the ManagedObjectContext, but as apple docs say, "Key-value coding does not perform validation automatically. It is, in general, your application’s responsibility to invoke the validation methods."